# Best way to save emails when switching hosting?

Tags: email, hosting

Im making a site for a client so they will be switching to my hosting. They already have old hosting with emails that they dont want to lose. Whats the best way to ensure emails aren't lost during the switch? I was simply thinking of getting them to change from IMAP to POP, but is there a better way? This relies on them setting up POP correctly and their not that technical. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Lower TTL on the domain name in DNS
- Wait a day or two for the new TTL to propagate
- Change the MX records to the new server
- Wait for it to propagate to all your nameservers. Then wait a little bit longer for the new TTL to expire.
- Move the mails using IMAP from the old server to the new one. All new mails should go to the new server now.

And for the sake of His Noodliness, *do not* use POP3 if you don't have a very good reason for it. IMAP is much more intuitive, enables access to all mails from different computers, is faster, supports folders (serverside) and searching, and also solves the problem with backups since it's easier to do backups on the serverside than on all the clients.

Comment: When you say 'Move the mails using IMAP from the old server to the new one', do I just drag and drop in my mail client to do this? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's one method. Another is to use a program or service specifically targeted for this.

Comment: So say I logged into the old hosting, set up imap on my mail client, and moved the emails with the mail client. When my client set up imap on their mail program for the new hosting, would all the emails be there? Thanks

Comment: If they used IMAP before, yes. Why don't you try it? You don't need to move the mail - just copy some of them, change computer and see if it worked.